# Static files not loading docker-compose, django, nginx

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose up all working good. I've got problem with static file after reboot. All containers starts, but on static files request we got 404.

Yet another time, problems begins after server reboot. When I say: 
`docker-compose up`
All working perfectly.

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: .
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn ems3.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8031
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8031:8031"
  links:
    - db
nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "8002:8002"   # 443
    - "8001:8001"   # 80
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web
db:
  restart: always
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5555:5555"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecr3333
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

nginx_config

```
server {
    listen 8002 ssl default;
    location /static {
        alias /code/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8031;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problems were decided by using docker-compose version 2 file format. Seems little differece, but it's working. docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn proj.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8031
    volumes:
      - web_code:/code
    ports:
      - "8031:8031"
    links:
      - db


volumes:
  web_code:
    driver: local
```

Added **version 2**, added named volume, and added volume with driver:local.
Few strings, but such painfull.

This is one more like me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36726663/2837890